# How do I write a script to rename and move a video file?

Tags: 16.04, python, dash-shell

On my media server I have files that I want to automatically move and rename after they have been watched (/NewEpisodes)
I want to move those file after they have been watched to a new directory (/OldEpisodes) and delete the directory

These files are in subdirectories by show.

Is it possible to use bash or Python or some other script to do this?

/TV/Show/file -----> /TV/Watched/Show/file

Answer (score 1):

A script is obvious

`move_file.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
mv /TV/Show/$1 /TV/Watched/Show/$1
```

Run the script this way:

```
sh move_file.sh file
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to scripting. Is there a way to rename it in the process and then delete the old directory?

Comment: Yes, it is possible and easy. But it is not quite clear what do you want to rename it too and which directory to delete.

Comment: And do you want a script or some commands to do it manually?